# Java code/library for generating slugs (for use in pretty URLs)

Tags: java, regex, seo, url-rewriting, slug

Web frameworks such as Rails and Django has built-in support for "slugs" which are used to generate readable and SEO-friendly URLs:

- [Slugs in Rails](https://wincent.com/wiki/Rails_slugs)
- [Slugs in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/in-django-what-is-a-slug)

A slug string typically contains only of the characters `a-z`, `0-9` and `-` and can hence be written without URL-escaping (think "foo%20bar").

I'm looking for a Java slug function that given any valid Unicode string will return a slug representation (`a-z`, `0-9` and `-`).

A trivial slug function would be something along the lines of:

```
return input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z0-9-]", "");
```

However, this implementation would not handle internationalization and accents (`ë` > `e`). One way around this would be to enumerate all special cases, but that would not be very elegant. I'm looking for something more well thought out and general.

My question:

- **What is the most general/practical way to generate Django/Rails type slugs in Java?**

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Normalize](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) your string using canonical decomposition:

```
  private static final Pattern NONLATIN = Pattern.compile("[^\\w-]");
  private static final Pattern WHITESPACE = Pattern.compile("[\\s]");

  public static String toSlug(String input) {
    String nowhitespace = WHITESPACE.matcher(input).replaceAll("-");
    String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(nowhitespace, Form.NFD);
    String slug = NONLATIN.matcher(normalized).replaceAll("");
    return slug.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
  }
```

This is still a fairly naive process, though. It isn't going to do anything for s-sharp (ß - used in German), or any non-Latin-based alphabet (Greek, Cyrillic, CJK, etc).

*Be careful when changing the case of a string. Upper and lower case forms are dependent on alphabets. In Turkish, the capitalization of U+0069 (**i**) is U+0130 (**İ**), not U+0049 (**I**) so you risk introducing a non-latin1 character back into your string if you use `String.toLowerCase()` under a Turkish locale.*

Comment: Looks promising, but the normalization does not appear to work: "fóòbâr" gets translated into "fbr" instead of expected "foobar". Do you know why?

Comment: Strange - when I put the string `"f\u00F3\u00F2b\u00e2r"` through the method, I get `"foobar"`. You are perhaps making an encoding error in your source or data file; see http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html

Comment: McDowell: You're absolutely right - it was an encoding error. Thanks for an excellent answer!

Answer (score 18):

[http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|slugify](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cslugify)

And here's the GitHub repository to take a look at the code and its usage:

[https://github.com/slugify/slugify](http://github.com/slugify/slugify)

Comment: Best and expandable solution so far.

Answer (score 12):

The proposition of McDowel almost works, but in cases like this `Hello World !!` it returns `hello-world--` (note the `--` at the end of the string) instead of `hello-world`.

A fixed version could be:

```
private static final Pattern NONLATIN = Pattern.compile("[^\\w-]");
private static final Pattern WHITESPACE = Pattern.compile("[\\s]");
private static final Pattern EDGESDHASHES = Pattern.compile("(^-|-$)");

public static String toSlug(String input) {
    String nowhitespace = WHITESPACE.matcher(input).replaceAll("-");
    String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(nowhitespace, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    String slug = NONLATIN.matcher(normalized).replaceAll("");
    slug = EDGESDHASHES.matcher(slug).replaceAll("");
    return slug.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I've extended the answer by @McDowell to include escaping punctuation as hyphens and to remove duplicate and leading/trailing hyphens.

```
  private static final Pattern NONLATIN = Pattern.compile("[^\\w_-]");  
  private static final Pattern SEPARATORS = Pattern.compile("[\\s\\p{Punct}&&[^-]]");  

  public static String makeSlug(String input) {  
    String noseparators = SEPARATORS.matcher(input).replaceAll("-");
    String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(noseparators, Form.NFD);
    String slug = NONLATIN.matcher(normalized).replaceAll("");
    return slug.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).replaceAll("-{2,}","-").replaceAll("^-|-$","");
  }
```