# How do I detect unicode characters in a Java string?

Tags: java, string, unicode

Suppose I have a string that contains Ü. How would I find all those unicode characters? Should I test for their code? How would I do that?

For example, given the string "AÜXÜ", I'd like to transform it to "AYXY". I'd like to do the same for other unicode characters, and I would hate to have to store them in a translation map of some sort.

Comment: How do you know what Ü will map to without your own map? There is no simple mapping and I suspect in different languages any mapping might differ

Comment: actually you can do it by looking at chars one by one. It depends the "range" of the char, but it's quiet low level, and I assume there already exists something to achieve this task.
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: Also see the solution here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_control_codes_and_extended_characters_from_a_string#Java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The definition of "unicode characters" is vague, but will be taken to mean UTF-8 characters not covered by the standard [ISO 8859 charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). If this is true in your case, then loop through all characters in the String and test its codepoint to determine whether it is within the given character set.

Alternatively, use a `Map<Character, Character>` and characters in the map that contain match the keys. For example:

```
Map<Character, Character> charReplacementMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>() {{
    put('Ü', 'Y');
    // Put more here.
}};

String originalString = "AÜAÜ";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (char currentChar : originalString.toCharArray()) {
    Character replacementChar = charReplacementMap.get(currentChar);
    builder.append(replacementChar != null ? replacementChar : currentChar);
}

String newString = builder.toString();
```

Or, do you mean "all characters with diacritics"? If so, then use [`java.text.Normalizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) to remove diacritical marks:

```
/**
 * Remove any diacritical marks (accents like ç, ñ, é, etc) from
 * the given string (so that it returns plain c, n, e, etc).
 * @param string The string to remove diacritical marks from.
 * @return The string with removed diacritical marks, if any.
 */
public static String removeDiacriticalMarks(String string) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

One pitfall, Ü would become U, not Y. Not sure if that's what you're after. If you want to replace by pronounced character, you'll really need to create a mapping. Sure, it's a tedious work, but it's done in less time than you needed to follow this topic.

Comment: It's how I usually did it. But this would require you add each character in the map.

Comment: I don't see any other efficient option to replace a certain character by a certain character and that for more than one character.

Comment: If you don't add each character to the map, how do you define the replacement?  Or do you want all non-ascii characters replaced by a single ascii character?

Comment: @BalusC - actually, the real definition of what is a Unicode character (codepoint) is very precise.  The problem is that the OP does not understand that the ASCII characters are a proper subset of the Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Or do you just want to remove diacritical marks? I've edited my post with it.

Comment: That normalizer was really great. Now I don't need to replace anything anymore. Will this work regardless of encoding?

Comment: @Geo NFD form will separate combined characters into a separate character and accent (NFC does the opposite). `"\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+"` will match the accents for replacement. But do you need to handle Greek letters, or Japanese text, and so on?

Comment: @McDowell: sounds like Turkish only. At least, I don't know any other language where Ü is pronounced as Y.

Answer (score 16):

You could loop through your string and for every character call

```
If (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) != Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN) {
 // replace with Y
}
```

Comment: Good one to test codepoints, but I don't have the impression that he want to replace *every* character by Y.

Comment: Well he says unicode characters by that I understand that he probably means replace all non ascii characters with Y. whatever

Answer (score 12):

You could go the other way round and ask if the character is an ascii character.

```
public static boolean isAscii(char ch) {
    return ch < 128;
}
```

You'd have to analyse the string char by char then of course.

(the method is from [commons-lang CharUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils.html) which contains loads of useful Character methods)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear to me exactly what is gained by transforming "AÜXÜ" to "AYXY". Is this because Ü is pronounced like Y in a particular language? What language? And what other rules might apply?

---

In terms of terminology...

```
"a"
```

The above is a Unicode string. It contains a single UTF-16 encoded character.

If you wish to limit the range of characters to the English alphabet, have a look at the [Normalization performed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657193/java-code-library-for-generating-slugs-for-use-in-pretty-urls/1657250#1657250).

Comment: It was just a replacement example. I'll actually replace the character by `_XX_` :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your example what you're trying to do - if you're just trying to replace all non-ASCII values with Y, then you could loop through the string looking for codepoints outside of the range 0 to 127, and replace them those code points with Y.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Character` also offers some interesting methods. Take a look at it.

```
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('a') == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN; //true

Character.UnicodeBlock.of('�') == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN; //false
```