# better alternative in letters substitution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any better alternative to this?

```
name.gsub('è','e').gsub('à','a').gsub('ò','o').gsub('ì','i').gsub('ù','u')
```

thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  Why would you want to remove the accents? Also, there are about 10 different ways to accent a letter in Unicode.  You are only showing the grave accent.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic for a list of different marks that you may have missed.

Comment: Agreed with JG.  Whatever it is that demands unaccented characters is at fault.

Comment: Seems like a dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225471/how-do-i-replace-accented-latin-characters-in-ruby to me

Comment: @John Gietzen: There are very legitimate uses for this. Try googling for "creme brulee".

Comment: @Thomas I don't see your point. Try googling for "Crème brûlée." Same results.

Comment: @Ben: That is exactly my point. Those characters are treated as equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
substitutes = {'è'=>'e', 'à'=>'a', 'ò'=>'o', 'ì'=>'i', 'ù'=>'u'}
substitutes.each do |old, new| 
    name.gsub!(old, new)
end
```

Or you could use [an extension of String such as this one](http://www.techniconseils.ca/en/scripts-remove-accents-ruby.php) to do it for you.

Answer (score 9):

Use [tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000830).

Maybe like `string.tr('èàòìù', 'eaoiu')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a full solution, try pulling the tables from [Perl's Unidecode module](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Text-Unidecode/).  After translating those tables to Ruby, you'll want to loop over each character of the input, substituting the table's value for that character.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild stab in the dark, but if you're trying to remove the accented characters because you're using a legacy text encoding format you should look at `Iconv`.

An introduction which is great on the subject: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/encoding_conversion_with_iconv

Answer (score 0):

In case you are wondering the technical terms for what you want to do is Case Folding and possibly Unicode Normalization (and sometimes collation).

Here is [a case folding configuration for ThinkingSphinx](http://darwinweb.net/articles/76-thinking_sphinx_case_folding_configuration) to give you an idea of how many characters you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If JRuby is an option, see the answer to my question:

[How do I detect unicode characters in a Java string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673544/how-do-i-detect-unicode-characters-in-a-java-string)

It deals with removing accents from letters, using a Normalizer. You could access that class from JRuby.