# URL Decode in Java 6

Tags: java

I see that `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(String)` is deprecated in 6.

I have the following String:

```
String url ="http://172.20.4.60/jsfweb/cat/%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9"
```

How should I decode it in Java 6?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<strike>Now you need to specify the character encoding of your string. Based off the information on the [`URLDecoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) page:</strike>

> Note: The World Wide Web Consortium
>   Recommendation states that UTF-8
>   should be used. Not doing so may
>   introduce incompatibilites.

The following should work for you:

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Please see [Draemon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519746/url-decode-in-java-6#6603584) below.

Comment: -1 this is just plain wrong. The documentation clearly states that this method uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is only used for the query string.

Comment: -1 see my comments on @Draemon's correct answer below.

Comment: This would be the correct answer, if the question were correct! If you  were using the one-arg version of decode() correctly, you should use the two-argument version.

Comment: +1 For directing users to the other answer. :)

Comment: This answer is in fact correct, since the form encoding referenced defers to URL encoding. The *media*-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` refers to the encoding used for URL's, and the detailed rules specified by `URLDecoder` make it clear that it's perfectly valid for use in decoding a URL. So it's simpler, and probably faster to use `URLDecoder`. I recommend that you unstrike this answer.

Answer (score 58):

You should use [java.net.URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) to do this, as the URLDecoder class does x-www-form-urlencoded decoding which is wrong (despite the name, it's for form data).

Comment: @whoever downvoted: care to elaborate on which part of this is wrong?

Comment: This is the correct answer! This trips people up all the time.

URLEncoder/URLDecoder encode and decode form data *for* URLs, not URLs themselves. The URL class provides the encoding and decoding of the URL itself. And the URI class is an updated, better specified, more general API -- every URL string is also a URI string, so use URI for parsing duties. The URL class itself warns against confusing the use of URLEncoder/Decoder: "The URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes can also be used, but only for HTML form encoding, which is not the same as the encoding scheme defined in RFC2396."

Comment: java.net.URI.decode() is private now

Comment: The *media*-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` refers to the encoding used for URL's, and the detailed rules specified by `URLDecoder` make it clear that it's perfectly valid for use in decoding a URL. So it's simpler, and probably faster to use `URLDecoder`.

Comment: URLDecoder will replace "+" with " ", which is incorrect.  "+" should only be changed to " " in the query string keys and values.

Answer (score 7):

As [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) mentions, `decode(String)` is deprecated because it always uses the platform default encoding, which is often wrong.

Use the [two-argument version instead](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). You will need to specify the encoding used n the escaped parts.

Answer (score 5):

Only the `decode(String)` method is deprecated. You should use the `decode(String, String)` method to explicitly set a character encoding for decoding.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by previous posters, you should use java.net.URI class to do it:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Decoded URI: '%s'", new URI(url).getPath()));
```

What I want to note additionally is that if you have a path fragment of a URI and want to decode it separately, the same approach with one-argument constructor works, but if you try to use four-argument constructor **it does not**:

```
String fileName = "Map%20of%20All%20projects.pdf";
URI uri = new URI(null, null, fileName, null);
System.out.println(String.format("Not decoded URI *WTF?!?*: '%s'", uri.getPath()));
```

This was tested in Oracle JDK 7. The fact that this does not work is counter-intuitive, runs contrary to JavaDocs and it should be probably considered a bug.

It could trip people who are trying to use an approach symmetrical to encoding. As noted for example in this post: "[how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java)", in order to **encode** URI, it's a good idea to construct a URI by passing different URI parts separately since different encoding rules apply to different parts:

```
String fileName2 = "Map of All projects.pdf";
URI uri2 = new URI(null, null, fileName2, null);
System.out.println(String.format("Encoded URI: '%s'", uri2.toASCIIString()));
```