# Unable to decode russing string with encodeURIComponent and java.net.decode

Tags: java, javascript, encoding, utf-8, urlencode

I have a russian string `"этикетка"`. This is need to send to a web service, before sending to the web service i use encodeURIComponent to encode the string and it gives me:

> '%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0'

On the web service side is receive the string and decode it using the following code:

```
String strLbl = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(label);
```

but i don't get the string properly. It looses formatting and I get `ѿтикетка`. 
Can you please suggest how can i overcome this or what is the ideal way to send russian string

Thanks and regards

Comment: You can maybe find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519746/url-decode-in-java-6#6603584

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the link given by NULL, decode(string) is now Deprecated in the favour of decode(string, encoding)

I would guess that the encoding and decoding method are not using the same page code.

Did you try to force UTF-8 during both process?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question be the formatting of it.

<s>Use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to decode url encoded strings in JavaScript:</s>

```
> decodeURIComponent('%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0')
"этикетка";
```

Comment: No i am not decoding it in the browser. I want to decode it in java code since it call web service. I am using java.net.decode(label) but it not decoding it properly. Original string: этикетка after decoding i get: ѿтикетка

Comment: I think he's asking how to decode the string correctly server-side, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: URI class has no method for decoding an already encoded string. Can you please elborate how to do it using URI class