# Unescaping by StringEscapeUtil from apache

Tags: java, escaping, apache-commons

There is a string: `Character\5C&\22\3C\3E'` I want to unescape.

There is a code for that:

```
package escaping;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class UnEscapingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("Character\\5C&\\22\\3C\\3E'");

       System.out.println(str);

    }

}
```

But in the end I have not expecting result. I have the same what I've put.. (without converting it)".

Why?

--

**Edit:**

I [believe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) that "3E" here is stands for ">" .. for example

So, my expecting string is: `Character\&"<>'`

Comment: Please clarify: what's the result you get, and what's the result you're expecting?

Comment: You're not putting in Html, that's the reason.  I don't know what that is that you're putting in though.

Comment: Is it really HTML you expect to escape here?

Comment: ok. let me think about it.. I got this value from ldap. And feel i should unescape it.

Comment: so, I believe then it is about unending but not unescaping

Comment: What does this have to do with OpenLDAP?

Answer (score 1):

What you mention is not HTML but URI encoding. In HTML, `<` would be `&lt;` and `>` would be `&gt;`.

You should take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519746/url-decode-in-java-6), and read both Tim Cooper and Draemon posts.

Comment: This is not even URI encoding. Backslashes are not legal in URIs.

Comment: I meant that for the edit part of the question (`I believe that "3E" here is stands for ">"`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that weird syntax of escaping comes from OpenLdap...

This works for me then:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String input = "Character\\5C&\\22\\3C\\3E'";

       input = input.replace("\\", "%");

       String result = URLDecoder.decode(input, "UTF-8");

       System.out.println(result);

    }
```