# In Java, How to detect if a string is unicode escaped

Tags: java, unicode, properties

I have a property file which may/ may not contain unicode escaped characters in the values of its keys. Please see the sample below. My job is to ensure that if a value in the property file contains a non-ascii character, then it should be unicode escaped. So, in the sample below, first entry is OK, all entries like the second entry should be removed and converted to like the first entry.

`##sample.properties

escaped=cari\u00F1o

nonescaped=cariño

normal=darling`

Essentially my question is how can I differentiate in Java between **cari\u00F1o** and **cariño** since as far as Java is concerned it treats them as identical.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673544/how-do-i-detect-unicode-characters-in-a-java-string should help.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/774153/828193) could also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties files in Java **must** be saved in the ISO-8859-1 character set for Java to read them properly.  That means that it is possible to use special characters from Western European languages without escaping them.  It is not possible to use characters from other languages such as those from Easter Europe, Russia, or China without escaping them.

As such there are only a few non-ascii characters that *can* appear in a properties file without being escaped.

To detect whether characters have been escaped or not, you will need to open the properties file directly, rather than through the Properties class.  The Properties class does all the unescaping for you when you load a file through it.  You should open them using the File class or though System.getResourceAsStream as an InputStream.  Once you do so you can scan through the input stream one byte at a time and ensure that all bytes are in the 0x20-0x7E range plus new lines \r and \n which is the [ASCII range of characters](http://ostermiller.org/calc/ascii.html) you would expect in a properties file.

I would suggest that your translators don't try to write properties files directly.  They should provide you with documents like spreadsheets that you convert into properties file.  Or they could use a [translation editor such as Attesoro](http://attesoro.org/) (which I wrote) to let them save the properties files properly escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `native2ascii` tool, which performs exactly this conversion (it will convert all non-ASCII characters to escapes but leave existing escapes intact).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the Java `Properties` class *decodes* the properties files, assuming ISO-8859-1 encoding, and *parsing* escaped unicode characters.

So from a `Properties` point of view, these two strings are indeed the same.

I believe if you need to differentiate these two, you will *need to write your own parser*.

It's actually a feauture that you do not need to care by default. The one thing that strikes me as the most odd is that the (only) encoding is ISO-8859-1, probably for historical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The library [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j) seems to be what you're looking for. See the [Normalization](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/normalization) page.