# Java Check String Special Character

Tags: java, special-characters

I have a string that contains: ½

From my understand i belive this is `\uFFFD`

Can someone help me with why this syntax does not work:

```
if (promotions.getText().contains("\uFFFD")) {
                return promotions;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect unicode characters in a Java string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673544/how-do-i-detect-unicode-characters-in-a-java-string)

Comment: why not use `if (promotions.getText().contains("½")) {
                return promotions;
}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

½ is \u00BD

Therefore this should work

```
if (promotions.getText().contains("\u00BD")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (promotions.getText().contains("\u00BD"))
{ 
    return promotions;
}
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it's not really a good answer, since it doesn't teach the OP. Instead it gives an alternative solution without explanation. This will usually lead to OP not learning, and coming back for asking a new question when a similar problem occurs. Would you mind adding some explanation?