# Using COLLATE in Android SQLite - Locales is ignored in LIKE statement

Tags: android, database, sqlite, locale, collate

When creating my SQLite database in Android I set the database locale - db.setLocale(new Locale("cz_CZ")). This is a Czech locale.

A SELECT statement works and takes the locale into account, for example:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name='sctzy' COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

Will find the entry 'ščťžý'.

But using LIKE will fail:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name LIKE '%sctzy%' COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

No row is returned.

BTW. There is no java.text.Normalized class in Android. I thought I could make a second column with a normalized text, stripped of special characters, which would be used for searching - but I am missing a class or way how to normalize the String.

Comment: I found a partial answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211974/transforming-some-special-caracters-e-e-into-e
But that's only how to remove accents. I would have to make a duplicate column in my database with a normalized text... Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [SQLite documentation for LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)? It has come information about non ASCII characters and a bug. Maybe Android has an older version of SQLite installed where this is a problem.

I think the second normalised column might be your best option unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Just today i had exactly the same task as you had. And in my situation making additional shadow columns is not a case because i'm having to search more than one column. So i came to the solution like this, which is tested in real project. In my case i'm handling only lower case letters but you can extend the function with upper case letters as well.

```
db.setLocale(Locale("cz", "CZ"))
val query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name GLOB ${getExpr(str)} ORDER BY name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC"

private fun getExpr(input: String) : String{
    var expr = ""
    for(lettter in input){
        expr += when(lettter){
            's','š' -> "[sš]"
            'a','á' -> "[aá]"
            'e','ě','é' -> "[eěé]"
            'i','í' -> "[ií]"
            'z','ž' -> "[zž]"
            'c','č' -> "[cč]"
            'y','ý' -> "[yý]"
            'r','ř' -> "[rř]"
            'u','ů','ú' -> "[uůú]"
            'o','ó' -> "[oó]"
            'n','ň' -> "[nň]"
            'd','ď' -> "[dď]"
            't','ť' -> "[tť]"
            else -> lettter
        }
     }
     return "'*${expr}*'"
}
```

Comment: For extending to upper case letters I just added: `...in input.lowercase()...` and for each row `'s','š' -> "[sšSŠ]"`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a second normalised column can be used to go around limitations (as mentioned briefly in other answers).

This means in practice that you have to create another (shadow) column of your first where the same data in a fixed case (e.g. all upper chars) is stored. Case insensitive queries (including like queries) can be made on this new column with search values in the same case.

If the first column "a" contains
<kbd>AAA</kbd>
<kbd>aaa</kbd>
<kbd>Bbb</kbd>
<kbd>äää</kbd>
<kbd>ééé</kbd>
The second column a_shadow would contain for the same rows
<kbd>AAA</kbd>
<kbd>AAA</kbd>
<kbd>BBB</kbd>
<kbd>ÄÄÄ</kbd>
<kbd>ÉÉÉ</kbd>

and your original query (example) "select a from mytable where a='äää'"
would be replaced with "select a from mytable where A='ÄÄÄ'"

Your code needs to be updated to fill the converted shadow content when adding the primary content.
If the column is added after creation or you cannot change the code existing values may need to be converted using an update query. Example:

`UPDATE mytable SET a_shadow=UPPER(a);`

Answer (score 2):

In Android sqlite, `LIKE` and `GLOB` ignore both `COLLATE LOCALIZED` and `COLLATE UNICODE` (they only work for `ORDER BY`). However, as @asat explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53535409/6766261), you can use `GLOB` with a pattern that will replace each letter with all the available alternatives of that letter. In Java:

```
public static String addTildeOptions(String searchText) {
    return searchText.toLowerCase()
                     .replaceAll("[aáàäâã]", "\\[aáàäâã\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[eéèëê]", "\\[eéèëê\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[iíìî]", "\\[iíìî\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[oóòöôõ]", "\\[oóòöôõ\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[uúùüû]", "\\[uúùüû\\]")
                     .replace("*", "[*]")
                     .replace("?", "[?]");
}
```

And then (not literally like this, of course):

```
SELECT * from table WHERE lower(column) GLOB "*addTildeOptions(searchText)*"
```

This way, for example in Spanish, a user searching for either *mas* or *más* will get the search converted into *m[aáàäâã]s*, returning both results.

It is important to notice that `GLOB` ignores `COLLATE NOCASE`, that's why I converted everything to lower case both in the function and in the query. Notice also that the `lower()` function in sqlite doesn't work on non-ASCII characters - but again those are probably the ones that you are already replacing!

The function also replaces both `GLOB` wildcards, `*` and `?`, with "escaped" versions.

Comment: I had to fix your regex to get it working, because it is inverted. Where is `.replaceAll("[aáàäâã]", "\\[aáàäâã\\]")` I had to use `.replaceAll("\\.*[aáàäâã]\\.*", "[aáàäâã]")`

Answer (score 0):

Might be time consuming, but you can use the java.text.Normalizer like here

[Converting Symbols, Accent Letters to English Alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)

As is not part of the java subset that Android, you may try to look for it at the code of java, such as [Normalizer.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/text/Normalizer.java.html)
With the Javadoc found [here](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html):

And copy the part of the code needed inside your project.

Hope it works!