# How to use SQL COLLATE operator with Android CursorLoader

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, collation

I need to create CursorLoader which will extract all items matching a name and type. What is more name must ignore Locale specific letters (accents). For example, if I provide query with:

```
item_name LIKE '%cafe%' COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

then I need then to extract all items, which names contain 'cafe' OR 'café'. I have no idea tho, how to provide COLLATE operator to query built like that (with no plain SQL).

```
    return CursorLoader(
            context,
            someUri,
            arrayOf(
                    PrompterTable.WORD_C,
                    PrompterTable.WORD_PLAIN_C,
                    PrompterTable.ENTRY_ID_C,
                    PrompterTable.CATEGORY_ID_C,
                    lengthClause,
                    PrompterTable.FAVOURITE_C
            ),
            "item_name LIKE ? COLLATE LOCALIZED AND item_type IN (0, 1)",
            arrayOf(myItemName),
            "L" //alias given to lengthClause before
    )
```

I did set database locale to spanish, I also tryied few ways to build the WHERE statement:

```
"item_name LIKE ? COLLATE LOCALIZED AND item_type IN (0, 1)"
"(item_name LIKE ? COLLATE LOCALIZED) AND item_type IN (0, 1)"
"item_name LIKE ? AND item_type IN (0, 1) COLLATE LOCALIZED"
"item_name = ? AND item_type IN (0, 1) COLLATE LOCALIZED"
"item_name = ? COLLATE LOCALIZED AND item_type IN (0, 1)"
"(item_name = ? COLLATE LOCALIZED) AND item_type IN (0, 1)"
```

But every of them won't work I as need (finds only 'cafe'). Query is computed to something like this:

```
    SELECT word, item_name, entryID, item_type,  length(word) as L , favourite 
    FROM item_table 
    WHERE (item_name LIKE '%cafe%' COLLATE LOCALIZED AND item_type IN (0, 1)) 
    GROUP BY word ORDER BY L LIMIT 25
```

I tried to reference this topic: [Using COLLATE in Android SQLite - Locales is ignored in LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480999/using-collate-in-android-sqlite-locales-is-ignored-in-like-statement/3481298)

But in my case it won't work even with '=' instead of LIKE

Comment: Hey Michal, I have a small suggestion, have you considered to move it to objects? Maybe it's going to be easier to handle the exceptions or cases that you want to consider.

Comment: If you mean moving filtering to the code then yeah. But there are 2 problems: legacy code which will be more efficient with this solution (and I was explicitly asked to make it using SQL) and second is that Java Collator is not working good with some letters (for example polish a and ą will not be compared well) so it will be even more coding to do it around :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, but it is not what I hoped for. Convenient COLLATE LOCALIZED was removed from Android around Nougat release and is not replaced in any way.

Known workarounds are:

- Perform filtering in coding (use Normalizer.normalize or Collator java object)
- Add additional column to the filtered table with normalized name (no accents etc.) and compare your users input to this column
- Add custom COLLATOR to SQLite database, what sounds cool but there is not Java API to do so. You would have to use Anroid NDK and write it in C++ code.

I found these in hire if you wish to get detailed answears:
https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/workaround-for-using-androids-localized-collator-after-3-5-0-update/1515/14