# How can I generate URL slugs in Perl?

Tags: perl, seo, url-rewriting, cpan

Web frameworks such as Rails and Django has built-in support for "slugs" which are used to generate readable and SEO-friendly URLs:

- [Slugs in Rails](https://wincent.com/wiki/Rails_slugs)
- [Slugs in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/in-django-what-is-a-slug)

A slug string typically contains only of the characters `a-z`, `0-9` and `-` and can hence be written without URL-escaping (think "foo%20bar").

I'm looking for a Perl slug function that given any valid Unicode string will return a slug representation (`a-z`, `0-9` and `-`).

A super trivial slug function would be something along the lines of:

```
$input = lc($input),
$input =~ s/[^a-z0-9-]//g;
```

However, this implementation would not handle internationalization and accents (I want `ë` to become `e`). One way around this would be to enumerate all special cases, but that would not be very elegant. I'm looking for something more well thought out and general.

My question:

- **What is the most general/practical way to generate Django/Rails type slugs in Perl?** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657193/java-code-library-for-generating-slugs-for-use-in-pretty-urls) is how I solved the same problem in Java.

Comment: Do it the same way you did in Java. Is there a particular operation that you don't know how to translate?

Comment: brian: Yes, the operation I didn't know how to translate was "String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(nowhitespace, Form.NFD);". Unicode::Normalize solved it. See Cameron's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`slugify` filter](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L219) currently used in Django translates (roughly) to the following Perl code:

```
use Unicode::Normalize;

sub slugify($) {
    my ($input) = @_;

    $input = NFKD($input);         # Normalize (decompose) the Unicode string
    $input =~ tr/\000-\177//cd;    # Strip non-ASCII characters (>127)
    $input =~ s/[^\w\s-]//g;       # Remove all characters that are not word characters (includes _), spaces, or hyphens
    $input =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;      # Trim whitespace from both ends
    $input = lc($input);
    $input =~ s/[-\s]+/-/g;        # Replace all occurrences of spaces and hyphens with a single hyphen

    return $input;
}
```

Since you also want to change accented characters to unaccented ones, throwing in a call to `unidecode` (defined in `Text::Unidecode`) before stripping the non-ASCII characters seems to be your best bet ([as pointed out by phaylon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009281/perl-code-library-for-generating-slugs-for-use-in-pretty-urls/4009423#4009423)).

In that case, the function could look like:

```
use Unicode::Normalize;
use Text::Unidecode;

sub slugify_unidecode($) {
    my ($input) = @_;

    $input = NFC($input);          # Normalize (recompose) the Unicode string
    $input = unidecode($input);    # Convert non-ASCII characters to closest equivalents
    $input =~ s/[^\w\s-]//g;       # Remove all characters that are not word characters (includes _), spaces, or hyphens
    $input =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;      # Trim whitespace from both ends
    $input = lc($input);
    $input =~ s/[-\s]+/-/g;        # Replace all occurrences of spaces and hyphens with a single hyphen

    return $input;
}
```

The former works well for strings that are primarily ASCII, but falls short when the entire string is formed of non-ASCII characters, since they all get stripped out, leaving you with an empty string.

Sample output:

```
string        | slugify       | slugify_unidecode
-------------------------------------------------
hello world     hello world     hello world
北亰                            bei-jing
liberté         liberta         liberte
```

Note how 北亰 gets slugifies to nothing with the Django-inspired implementation. Note also the difference the NFC normalization makes -- liberté becomes 'liberta' with NFKD after stripping out the second part of the decomposed character, but would becomes 'libert' after stripping out the re-assembled 'é' with NFC.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Unidecode/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm)?

Answer (score 3):

[`String::Dirify`](http://p3rl.org/String%3a%3aDirify) is used for making slugs in the blogging software Movable Type/Melody.

Comment: Tested with some Chinese, it seems what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Adding [Text::Unaccent](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=text%3A%3Aunaccent&mode=all) to the beginning of the chain looks like it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The most turn-key solution is using [Text::Slugify](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Slugify) which does what you need. It's a trivial amount of code which nicely provides a `slugify` function for you.

It relies on [Text::Unaccent::PurePerl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Unaccent::PurePerl) to remove accents from characters.