# What does "slug" mean

Tags: database, couchdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the etymology of 'slug'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug)

In CouchDB definitive guide the author used key "slug" in a document.

```
{
   "title": "Hello World",
   "slug": "hello_world"
}
```

What does "slug" mean and why is it used?

Comment: See [What is the etymology of 'slug'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug).  The answers explain both the etymology and meaning.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug

Comment: This is a question that programmers will want answered.
The "Possible Duplicate" is closed too.

Comment: We love closing questions around here @BrentBradburn - I think there's some financial incentive for admins - 2c per closed question if it remains closed for at least 6 months, something like that.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

A slug is an alternative to a name that would otherwise not be acceptable for various reasons - e.g. containing special characters, too long, mixed-case, etc. - appropriate for the target usage. What target usage means is context dependent, but could include usage in a URL or name of a file or database table for example. In the general case a slug may be composed from a combination of multiple fields; in the above case, only one field is used - title.

Have a look at these SOqs, too:

- [What is a "slug" in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/in-django-what-is-a-slug)
- [Replacing %20 with a Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116796/replacing-20-with-a-dash)

If you are into the origin of the term, see this:

- [What is the etymology of 'slug'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug)

Comment: You can watch this http://slugify.net/

Comment: What about the meaning of "slug" in this context? Where does it come from?