# How to work with django SlugField and slugify?And How to use it properly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I google about how to use slug and already watched some videos.But I am confused how does this work. Help me by Giving Some Example or Any Resources. It will be be very helpful for me.

Thanks Good People.

Comment: [This](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-slug-tutorial) would be a good starter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357007/what-does-slug-mean did you look up there?