# Javascript: match slug of a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

For a given URL I want to retrieve its slug using Javascript and a regular expression. I tried the following but it only matches `h` and not `This-is-the-slug-to-be-matched`.

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/region/town/This-is-the-slug-to-be-matched;art6066,1184999";
var slug = url.match(/[a-z0-9-]/);
```

Comment: What part of a URL is its "slug"?

Comment: @Gabe [etymology of "slug"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug)

Comment: I always read about "slug" as the readable part of a URL precisely describing the website's title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we can assume the slug always follows the last forward slash and precedes the first colon after the last forward slash:

```
> var url = "http://www.domain.com/region/town/This-is-the-slug-to-be-matched;art6066,1184999";
> var slug = url.split("/").pop().split(";")[0];
```

Output:

```
> console.log(slug);
  "This-is-the-slug-to-be-matched"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var slug = url.match(/.*\/([-a-z0-9]+)/i)[1];
```

`.*\/` skips over everything until the last `/`. `[-a-z0-9]+` matches 1 or more alphanumerics or hyphens. Putting the latter in `(...)` makes it a capture group, and `[1]` returns the first capture group.

Comment: Need to add missing closing bracket after `+` to make it work: `url.match(/.*\/([-a-z0-9]+)/i)` - initial version gives 'Invalid regular expression: Unterminated group'

Answer (score 2):

This gets the value after the last slash ( `/` ) and before the first semi-comma ( `;` ):

```
var slug = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.indexOf(';'));
```

So in this case, `slug == "This-is-the-slug-to-be-matched"`.

---

### Performance review

Comparing `.split.pop()` answers and `.subtring()` with `.lastIndexOf()` functions, my method is **[at least 35% faster](http://jsperf.com/js-split-vs-substring-indexof)**. Scoring **~4m ops/sec** against **~2.6m ops/sec**.

If performance is an important matter to you, you might want to consider my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not want to match the `art6066,1184999` part.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way (I am assuming you also want ;art6066,1184999 in slug)

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/region/town/This-is-the-slug-to-be-matched;art6066,1184999";   
var slug = url.split('/').pop();
```

#### Update based on cr0's comment

```
var slug = url.split('/').pop().split(';')[0];
```

Comment: I always thought that a slug is used to link to an article in a way you can remember. So I don't get why there are parameters like articleid which is hard to memorize.