# JS - Regexp to match slug in url if any

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any effective/good way to match slug in URL ?

For instance :

**match :**

- http://somepage.com/s/XXXXX/this-is-slug-i-want
- http://somepage.com/s/XXXXX/this-is-slug-i-want/
- http://somepage.com/s/XXXXX/this-is-slug-i-want?foo=bar
- http://somepage.com/s/XXXXX/this-is-slug-i-want#foo

**not to match :**

- http://somepage.com/s/XXXXX/somePage.html
  and similar (.php, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: match slug of a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754146/javascript-match-slug-of-a-url)

Comment: Please at least attempt a solution before asking on Stack Overflow. We're not a code-writing service. Also, as it says in [ask], please research before asking there have been a number of questions on this subject.

Comment: I'd go with `.*this-is-slug-i-want.*`

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Do you want the string to match to the Regexp? do you want to compare the last slug? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @sin that's incorrect, that regexp will match to things like `http://this-is-slug-i-want.com`, `http://somepage.coms/XXXXX/somePage.html?this-is-slug-i-want`, and a plethora of others that the OP definitely didn't want

Comment: @Wade - Well, I never heard the technical term `slug` before. Is that the definition you're inferring?

Comment: @sin yeah same, I'm pretty sure he means that it's in the filepath (this is probably not a term either) of the URL. That is to say, it's after the domain name such as `something.com/this-is-the-slug`, where `this-is-the-slug` is what the OP considers a "slug". Not sure if he wants it to be the last section of the URL though, or if he's okay with it matching to something like `something.com/this-is-slug-i-want/something-else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this...

```
http:\/\/somepage.com\/s\/XXXXX\/(?!.*\.html).*
```

Test: http://rubular.com/r/KyTWM1fizJ

Comment: This would match anything with the form `http://somepage.com/s/XXXXX/literally-anything-without-.html-in-it`, not what the poster asked.

Comment: Two other options then...
    `http:\/\/somepage.com\/s\/XXXXX\/(?!.*\.(html|php)).*`  or  `http:\/\/somepage.com\/s\/XXXXX\/(?!.*\..*).*`

Comment: Again, this is not what the poster asked. They want something where they have a slug they want to match but not other pages. They never said that slug can't have `.html` or `.php` or whatever other extension you can whip up in it. Yours just matches to any page without the specific suffix, not to a single desired slug as the poster asked.

Comment: Since it seems like you really want your solution to work, here's an example where yours fails. http://rubular.com/r/9bX47v2vJB

Comment: Clearly I am confused as to what OP wants.  Seems to me OP is trying to look for URLs that end in a folder or in a querystring, but not in a filename - I think my regex accomplishes that, but maybe that's not what OP wants - I admit to being a bad psychic.

Comment: My interpretation is that the OP wants to be able to specify which folder (not querystrying I'm pretty sure), but then again I guess he's not editing his question or responding to any of the comments so it's up in the air. I'm pretty sure he wants to be able to specify what folder or slug he wants at the end of his URL though

Answer (score 0):

Why not `/^http:\/\/.+\/this-is-the-slug-i-want\/?(\?.*)?/`

Comment: This `[\?[.*]?]?` should properly have been: `(\?.*?)?`

Comment: Haha definitely, thank you! Though just realized you don't need the second `?` ;)

Comment: That was not what I said, `[.*]` will match literal period (`.`) or literal asterisk  `*`

Comment: Whoops! Meant to delete those too :P I meant that in yours, you could just do `(\?.*)?` instead of `(\?.*?)?`