# Pass parameter with window.location.href to MVC ActionResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it and have seen a lot of suggestions, but can't get anything to work quite right and would rather do it the best way first.

Here's the ActionResult on the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string selectedArtist)
{
    //other code
    return View(selectedArtist)
}
```

Here's the javascript on the client:

```
$('#results').on('click', '.item', function () {
        var selectedArtist = $(this).data('artistInfo');
        var selectedId = encodeURIComponent('ARE602H1187FB3B8F8')
        var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Artist", new { id = "__id__" })';
        window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', selectedId);
    })
```

Ideally, I would like the pass the selectedArtist object to the controller. It's basically a javascript class that matches a Artist model I have. For now though as a test I am just trying to pass an Id as a string to the controller and can't get it to, it just always comes up as NULL.

The request that it's building looks pretty good to me ".../Artist/Details/ARE602H1187FB3B8F". However, I'm debugging and the parameter on the controller always ends up NULL.

Am I missing something? And/or is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options. Update your route table to properly allow the route with its [slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug) "ARE602H1187FB3B8F" to be routed to the applicable action method. Or, you could pass `id` as a query string parameter, thereby using the default route in your route table:

```
... Artist/Details?selectedArtist=ARE602H1187FB3B8F
```

Comment: doesn't the action method expects something else...`selectedArtist`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to MVC. When you say update the route table. Are you talking about the RouteConfig? Where you would be changing how it handles the URLs? i.e. url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" ..?

Comment: @mrshickadance yes, that's what i meant.