# create edit URL route that doesn't show :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the midst of trying to clean up my routing. I have a company model that can log in and create applications. They can create several.

Currently this is my setup:

**Routes**

```
get 'applications/edit/:id', to: 'applications#edit'
```

**Applications_controller**

```
def edit
 @application = current_company.applications.find(params[:id])
end 

def update
 @application = Application.find(params[:id])
 if @application.update(application_params)
  redirect_to dashboard_path
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end
```

Each company have their own dashboard. Here's my code from
**/dashboard**

## Your active applications

```
<% @applications.all.each do |f| %>
 <%= link_to "Application",   show_path + "/#{f.id}" %> | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_application_path("#{f.id}") %>
   <br>
<% end %>
```

Now this all works, if I go to edit_application/11 f.ex I see it.

**The thing I'd like changed is to remove the :id from the URL.**

Thus make it more secure and to give a nicer feel. Now it took me 5 minutes before I realised I could just change the :id url and edit everything. Thus I added the current_company.applications to stop that. Yet I don't feel like this is very secure.

Comment: I don't get it. You want the parameter not to be in the url?

Comment: I want to change it so that instead of this /edit/12  (where 12 is the current ID f.ex) that it just says /edit and gets the ID from the link in the @applications.all.each

Comment: try: `get 'applications/edit/:id', to: 'applications#edit' as: :edit_app`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the `:id`, you'll still need a way to find the data you want.

As long as you have the url `/edit/12` and as long as you use the id `12` in the `GET` url to find your content, it will show in the browser bar. The only way to "hide" it (but it's not more secure at all, because it's easily found out), is to use a `POST` request with a form containing a hidden field with the `id` (can be made in JavaScript).
You are asking the application to get the id from the link in the `@applications.all.each` but the only way it can do that is to include it somewhere in the request (be it GET, POST, COOKIES/SESSION, ...).

For another (possibly better) solution, read on.

A very common practice is to use `slug`s: you create a unique key for each content, for example, if your title is "My great app", the slug will be `my-great-app`. Thus there is **no `id` in your URL** (and it cannot be found out if you always use slugs as references). The advantage is that you'll still find a quick match for what you're searching for (creating an unique index on the `slug`s).

Some further reading about slugs:

http://rubysnippets.com/2013/02/04/rails-seo-pretty-urls-in-rails/

[What is the etymology of 'slug'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug)