# Is there a name for a string containing only lowercase alphanumeric characters and hyphens?

Tags: regex, string, url, naming

We're building a simple function that converts any string into lowercase alphanumeric characters and hyphens, e.g. "My Exciting 1st Example!" becomes "my-exciting-1st-example". This is specifically for creating URL parts.

I've previously called it "safe URL", but it's not technically a Unique Resource Location, and this spec certainly doesn't encompass the full set of safe URL characters. Given its common usage, is there a commonly used name for this state or process? Much like "alphanumeric" is a thing?

Comment: The URL for this very question on Stack Overflow is a good example of this: `is-there-a-name-for-a-string-containing-only-lowercase-alphanumeric-characters-a`

Comment: Actually, the term you're looking for is a slug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug/4230937#4230937

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those things are often called "slugs", and the process of making one would be to "slugify".

That's by no means universal, but I don't know of any other jargon for the concept.

#### References

- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) from comments
- [A slugifier](http://blog.tersmitten.nl/slugify/)
- [Origin of the term](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4230937/1566221) according to a SO answer.