# In Heroku, is slug an acronym?

Tags: heroku

The Heroku documentation just says:

> A slug is a bundle of your source, fetched dependencies, the language runtime, and compiled/generated output of the build system - ready for execution.

Where does the term slug come from? Does it have some origin within the company? Does its use come from the same place as wordpress slugs - ie from the newspaper industry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the etymology of 'slug'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug)

Comment: That question is referring to the url slugs in wordpress. This is a different question. I've add some clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the name "Slug" derives from Quake computer game terminology. The (non-public) software that Heroku uses to execute user code in dynos is named [Railgun](http://quake.wikia.com/wiki/Railgun_(Q3)) (I don't know why). The ammo-type for the railgun in Quake is a "Slug". Thus, the object that the Railgun software deploys ("fires") is a slug.

When we made [this part of the Heroku API public](https://blog.heroku.com/programmatically_release_code_to_heroku_using_the_platform_api#slugs-and-releases) we tried briefly to come up with a more self-explanatory name. This was before Docker and containers were really popularized, and I guess we decided that Slug was not too bad a name, and that it was ok for public use.

Answer (score 1):

No, slug is not an acronym.
I believe the name comes from the mollusc:

> a tough-skinned terrestrial mollusc which typically lacks a shell and secretes a film of mucus for protection. It can be a serious plant pest.

A slug being the container layer which contains your app's code can be seen as a small thing which lacks a shell (can't be executed without something on top of it, the stack image).
Obviously, slugs don't secrete a film of mucus.