# Mixed results with White Spaces, and add a dash in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you combine eliminating white-spaces and special characters with only a single '-' character? 
Here's a little Background: 
When publishing a job to my career section for my company, the ATS will turn a job title for the URL, e.g if a job title is:
**Olympia, WA: SLP Full or Part Time** it will become **olympia-wa-slp-full-or-part-time**

I've experimented from other similar questions, but have only come close with this bit of code:

```
function newTitle(str) {
var x = str.replace(/[\W]/g, '-').toLowerCase();
return x;
```

now if I run it, the output generated is **olympia--wa--slp-full-or-part-time** 
(has 2 dashes from the extra spaces). What am I not getting right?

I've tried the other following bits:

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

and

```
str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ");
```

but neither get close to the desired format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got pretty close in your first example, just add `+` after `[\W]` to match one or more non-word characters. You can also give it a try in [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)

```js
function newTitle(str) {
  var x = str.replace(/[\W]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  return x;
}

alert(newTitle('Olympia, WA: SLP Full or Part Time'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want, it looks like, is to create a [slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug) from a string.
Here is a nice reusable function that also takes care of multiple dashes:

```js
function slugify(s) {
  s = s.replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, '').trim().toLowerCase();
  s = s.replace(/[-\s]+/g, '-');
  return s;
}

console.log(
  slugify("Olympia, WA: SLP Full or Part Time")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last example [`[^a-zA-Z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/qIqOhu/1) almost works if you use a dash as the replacement. This uses a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match not what you specified so that would include whitespaces and special characters.

Note that if you have a job with for example a digit or an underscore that that would also be replaced. Your could expand the character class with what you don't want to be replaced like [`[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/ZV6dSW/1) or if you also want to keep the underscore [`\W+`](https://regex101.com/r/G6XGbN/1) as that would match `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```js
function newTitle(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
}
console.log(newTitle("Olympia, WA: SLP Full or Part Time"));
```