# How to get (category?slug? unsure) of a page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to capture url slug and title from `sidebar.php`. For example: if url is: `www.example.com/video-tuts/abc` for a page which title is: `awesome explanation of abc`

Now I want to get the portion of the url: `video-tuts` and title: `awesome explanation of abc` from `sidebar.php`. Any idea?

Comment: Wouldn't the slug be abc, not video-tuts?

Comment: I want to get parameter immediate after the main domain, I knew this is slug. if video-tuts is not slug, what is it?

Comment: In the Stack Over flow url of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug the `slug` is `what-is-the-etymology-of-slug` it has no purpose, except for making the url more readable for humans. Anything that has an actual purpose, other then increasing readability, is just a portion of the url path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to get the URL path information in PHP and then `explode()` that into an array to get the different parts.

**However**, if you just want to get the title of the post/page that is being viewed you can call `global $post;` in `sidebar.php` and then `$title = get_the_title($post->ID);` or `$post->post_title;` to get the title.

Comment: I think the Op may want the category? But I'm not 100% sure that's what it's called as my wordpress is a little rusty.