# React JS - How to Create a Dynamic URL Instead of Id Which is in Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema

How can I make the dynamic URL which is present in the Database as the link (tag) how can I use that link for fetching only one post from that database like an e-commerce website (it makes the new page for each post)

```
http://localhost:3000/{here is the link}
```

here is my code =>

Schema of Mongoose (link)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Posts = mongoose.model('Posts', {
    link: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:true
    },
    
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    
    });

module.exports = { Posts }
```

```
"addPosts": {
    "link": "newoneawesomed",
    "title": "How can we achieve sucessfully",}
```

Below I making for id that renders a separate post from MongoDB

like

```
http://localhost:3000/625d056d4e412fb823d9cc4e
```

But how can achieve instead of id?

is

```
http://localhost:3000/newoneawesomed
```

which is present in the database...

Pls...
help me to Solve these problems

Comment: I think you need [slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug) which will be generated from the post title uniquely.

Comment: How can i make the slug

Comment: That depends on your data. In your case, for the posts, you make a slug with the `title`. Refer: http://slugify.net/ and implement similar to it.

Comment: could you please share your code with that you search for items?

Comment: yes I am making that link tag a slug and then what should I do for using these slugs in my URL

Comment: hey Ifaruki i don't understand what are you saying