# String slugification in Python

Tags: python, slug

I am in search of the best way to "slugify" string [what "slug" is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/in-django-what-is-a-slug), and my current solution is based on [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577257-slugify-make-a-string-usable-in-a-url-or-filename/)

I have changed it a little bit to:

```
s = 'String to slugify'

slug = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)
slug = slug.encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower()
slug = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9]+', '-', slug).strip('-')
slug = re.sub(r'[-]+', '-', slug)
```

Anyone see any problems with this code? It is working fine, but maybe I am missing something or you know a better way?

Comment: are you working with unicode alot?  if so, the last re.sub might be better if you wrap unicode() around it,  This is what django does. Also, the [^a-z0-9]+ can be shortened to use \w .  see django.template.defaultfilters, it's close to yours, but a bit more refined.

Comment: Are unicode characters allowed in URL? Also, I have changed \w to a-z0-9 because \w includes _ character and uppercase letters. Letters are set to lowercase in advance, so there will be no uppercase letters to match.

Comment: '_' is valid (but your choice, you did ask), unicode is as percent encoded chars.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Well, I asked a wrong question. Is there any reason to encode it back to unicode string, if we already replaced all characters except "a-z", "0-9" and "-" ?

Comment: For django, I believe it's important to them to have it all strings as unicode objects for compatibility. It's your choice if you want this.

Comment: I did a pull request to the slugify (https://github.com/zacharyvoase/slugify) Python lib which addresses all the issues: https://github.com/ksamuel/slugify. Standalone pure python pip installable slugify using unicodata, or unidecode if installed. You can choose a custom separator and even keep all non ASCII characters. I hope it will be accepted soon and pushed to pypi.

Comment: in python 3.6 I had to add decoding back to string:

slug = slug.encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower().decode('ascii')

otherwise slug variable was converter to binary and re.sub was throwing exception.

Answer (score 211):

There is a python package named [`python-slugify`](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify), which does a pretty good job of slugifying:

```
pip install python-slugify
```

Works like this:

```
from slugify import slugify

txt = "This is a test ---"
r = slugify(txt)
self.assertEquals(r, "this-is-a-test")

txt = "This -- is a ## test ---"
r = slugify(txt)
self.assertEquals(r, "this-is-a-test")

txt = 'C\'est déjà l\'été.'
r = slugify(txt)
self.assertEquals(r, "cest-deja-lete")

txt = 'Nín hǎo. Wǒ shì zhōng guó rén'
r = slugify(txt)
self.assertEquals(r, "nin-hao-wo-shi-zhong-guo-ren")

txt = 'Компьютер'
r = slugify(txt)
self.assertEquals(r, "kompiuter")

txt = 'jaja---lol-méméméoo--a'
r = slugify(txt)
self.assertEquals(r, "jaja-lol-mememeoo-a")
```

See [More examples](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify)

This package does a bit more than what you posted (take a look at the source, it's just one file). The project is still active (got updated 2 days before I originally answered, over nine years later (last checked 2022-03-30), it still gets updated).

**careful**: There is a second package around, named `slugify`. If you have both of them, you might get a problem, as they have the same name for import. The one just named `slugify` didn't do all I quick-checked: `"Ich heiße"` became `"ich-heie"` (should be `"ich-heisse"`), so be sure to pick the right one, when using `pip` or `easy_install`.

Comment: `python-slugify` is licensed under MIT, but it uses `Unidecode` which is licensed under GPL, so it might not fit for some projects.

Comment: @Rotareti Could you please explain for me why it is could not fit all the projects? Can't we use anything under MIT or GPL license and include them inside commercial software? I think the only restriction is putting the license besides the codes we develop. Am I wrong?

Comment: @GhassemTofighi In short: You can use it in your commercial software, but if you use it, you must open source your code as well. Anyway IANAL and this is no legal advice.

Comment: @GhassemTofighi maybe take a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/47032/71504 on that topic

Comment: @Rotareti `python-slugify` now defaults to the Artistic License'd `text-unidecode` instead of the GPL-licensed `Unidecode`, addressing your licensing concern. https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify/commit/b8be7d69119dcceb9a3e0ce64a509415737190ac#diff-e4156a8bee1b298082516842836621b9

Answer (score 41):

Install unidecode form [from here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode#downloads) for unicode support

> pip install unidecode

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import unidecode

def slugify(text):
    text = unidecode.unidecode(text).lower()
    return re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '-', text)

text = u"My custom хелло ворлд"
print slugify(text)
```

> >>> my-custom-khello-vorld

Comment: hi, its a bit strange but it give for my res like that "my-custom-ndud-d-d3-4-d2d3-4nd-d-"

Comment: @derevo that happend when you don't send unicode strings. Replace `slugify("My custom хелло ворлд")` with `slugify(u"My custom хелло ворлд")`, and it should work.

Comment: I would suggest against using variable names like `str`. This hides the builtin `str` type.

Comment: unidecode is GPL, which may not be suitable for some.

Comment: What about the reslugifying or deslugifying.

Comment: @RyanChou that can't be done unambigiously, best effort you can do is something like replace "-" with space and make first letter uppercase, but you can't tell if "my-custom-khello-vorld" was "My custom хелло ворлд", or "MY ČUSTOM KHELLO-VORLD" or anything else that slugifies into that concrete slug

Comment: @M.Volf Got it.

Answer (score 12):

There is python package named [awesome-slugify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awesome-slugify):

```
pip install awesome-slugify
```

Works like this:

```
from slugify import slugify

slugify('one kožušček')  # one-kozuscek
```

[awesome-slugify github page](https://github.com/dimka665/awesome-slugify)

Comment: Nice package! But be careful, it's licensed under GPL.

Comment: Heads up: this won't automatically .lower() your urls. You'll need to run `slugify(text).lower()` if you want that.

Answer (score 9):

```
def slugify(value):
    """
    Converts to lowercase, removes non-word characters (alphanumerics and
    underscores) and converts spaces to hyphens. Also strips leading and
    trailing whitespace.
    """
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    value = re.sub('[^\w\s-]', '', value).strip().lower()
    return mark_safe(re.sub('[-\s]+', '-', value))
slugify = allow_lazy(slugify, six.text_type)
```

This is the slugify function present in django.utils.text
This should suffice your requirement.

Answer (score 8):

It works well in [Django](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L207), so I don't see why it wouldn't be a good general purpose slugify function.

Are you having any problems with it?

Comment: The code has moved to [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/92053acbb9160862c3e743a99ed8ccff8d4f8fd6/django/utils/text.py#L417).

Comment: For the lazies: `from django.utils.text import slugify`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with the ascii normalization line:

```
slug = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)
```

It is called [unicode normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) which does not decompose lots of characters to ascii. For example, it would strip non-ascii characters from the following strings:

```
Mørdag -> mrdag
Æther -> ther
```

A better way to do it is to use the [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) module that tries to transliterate strings to ascii. So if you replace the above line with:

```
import unidecode
slug = unidecode.unidecode(s)
```

You get better results for the above strings and for many Greek and Russian characters too:

```
Mørdag -> mordag
Æther -> aether
```

Answer (score 4):

Unidecode is good; however, be careful: unidecode is GPL. If this license doesn't fit then use [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/text-unidecode)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options on GitHub:

1. https://github.com/dimka665/awesome-slugify
2. https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify
3. https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify

Each supports slightly different parameters for its API, so you'll need to look through to figure out what you prefer.

In particular, pay attention to the different options they provide for dealing with non-ASCII characters. Pydanny wrote a very helpful blog post illustrating some of the unicode handling differences in these slugify'ing libraries: http://www.pydanny.com/awesome-slugify-human-readable-url-slugs-from-any-string.html This blog post is slightly outdated because Mozilla's `unicode-slugify` is no longer Django-specific.

Also note that currently `awesome-slugify` is GPLv3, though there's an open issue where the author says they'd prefer to release as MIT/BSD, just not sure of the legality: https://github.com/dimka665/awesome-slugify/issues/24

Answer (score 2):

Another good answer for creating it could be this form

```
import re
re.sub(r'\W+', '-', st).strip('-').lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider changing the last line to

```
slug=re.sub(r'--+',r'-',slug)
```

since the pattern `[-]+` is no different than `-+`, and you don't really care about matching just one hyphen, only two or more.

But, of course, this is quite minor.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [`boltons.strutils.slugify`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/strutils.html#boltons.strutils.slugify). [Boltons](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons) has quite a few other useful functions as well, and is distributed under a `BSD` license.

Answer (score 0):

By your example, a fast manner to do that could be:

```py
s = 'String to slugify'

slug = s.replace(" ", "-").lower()
```