# Using urlopen to open list of urls

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

I have a python script that fetches a webpage and mirrors it. It works fine for one specific page, but I can't get it to work for more than one. I assumed I could put multiple URLs into a list and then feed that to the function, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autowget.py", line 46, in <module>
    getUrl()
  File "autowget.py", line 43, in getUrl
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 139, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 361, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Here's the offending code:

```
url = ['https://www.example.org/', 'https://www.foo.com/', 'http://bar.com']
def getUrl(*url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
getUrl()
```

I've exhausted Google trying to find how to open a list with urlopen(). I found one way that sort of works. It takes a `.txt` document and goes through it line-by-line, feeding each line as a URL, but I'm writing this using Python 3 and for whatever reason `twillcommandloop` won't import. Plus, that method is unwieldy and requires (supposedly) unnecessary work.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply iterate over your list of URLs with a `for` loop?

Comment: That just came to mind when replying to sheng's comment! It would return the specific portion as a string, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there are some errors:

- You define getUrls with variable arguments list (the tuple in your error);
- You manage getUrls arguments as a single variable (list instead)

You can try with this code

```
import urllib2
import shutil

urls = ['https://www.example.org/', 'https://www.foo.com/', 'http://bar.com']
def getUrl(urls):
   for url in urls:
      #Only a file_name based on url string
      file_name = url.replace('https://', '').replace('.', '_').replace('/','_')
      response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
      with open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
         shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
getUrl(urls)
```

Comment: Thanks - earlier in my code I set the file name to `'/path/to/directory'` plus 'domain' where the 'domain' is the string between `http://www` and `.com` in the URL. 

The script both FTPs and pushes (via Git to GitHub pages) so I have to have a set file path or else the Git portion won't work. 

Anyway, thanks again! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It do not support tuple:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.
```

And your calling is incorrect. It should be:

```
getUrl(url[0],url[1],url[2])
```

And inside the function, use a loop like "for u in url" to travel all urls.

Comment: So I will have to create multiple variables? Unfortunate. And thanks. I appreciate it. But wouldn't there be an easier to pass a list? Instead of var[0], var[0], etc using a for loop?

Comment: No, you should use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should just iterate over your URLs using a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop:

```
import shutil
import urllib.request


urls = ['https://www.example.org/', 'https://www.foo.com/']

file_name = 'foo.txt'

def fetch_urls(urls):
    for i, url in enumerate(urls):
        file_name = "page-%s.html" % i
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

fetch_urls(urls)
```

I assume you want the content saved to *separate* files, so I used [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) here to create a uniqe file name, but you can obviously use anything from `hash()`, the [`uuid`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) module to creating [slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574042/string-slugification-in-python).