# Converting a string, removing special characters and replacing

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I need to convert my string so that it is made into a special format

ex:

```
string = "the cow's milk is a-okay!"

converted string = "the-cows-milk-is-a-okay"
```

Comment: This maybe `'-'.join(s.split())`, but your symbol removal requirement makes it vague

Comment: Sounds great. Tried anything yet?

Comment: Look at [String slugification in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574042/string-slugification-in-python)

Comment: Its good that you need something but can you tell us what have you done/tried on doing it? Don't just come here asking us to do your work. We are here to help you solve problems not to write all the code for you.

Comment: My first idea was make the string into a list by separated by spaces.  Then It was removing the special characters in each element of the list.  Finally joining the list into a string again with "-" in between elements

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

s = "the cow's milk is a-okay!"
s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s-]+', '', s)  # remove anything that isn't a letter, space, or hyphen
s = re.sub(r'\s+', '-', s)  # replace all spaces with hyphens
print(s)   # the-cows-milk-is-a-okay
```

Here a 'space' is any whitespace character including tabs and newlines. To change this, replace `\s` with the actual space character .

Runs of multiple spaces will be replaced by a single hyphen. To change this, remove the `+` in the second call to `re.sub`.

Comment: Would `\W+` be better?

Comment: @cricket_007 no, that wouldn't be correct for spaces, hyphens, or underscores.

Comment: @AlexHall Thank you so much! I really have to study this re more.

Comment: @AlexHall just erased the hyphen on the second line because my original string had a " - " not "-", and it started to replace the strings with "---" haha 
would not have found this without you.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this (the drawback is unable to remain the hyphen `-`),

```
import string

s = "the cow's milk is a-okay!"

table = string.maketrans(" ", "-") 
new_s = s.translate(table, string.punctuation)  

print(new_s)
# the-cows-milk-is-aokay
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wanted. Ironically, you acknowledge that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string = "the cow's milk is a-okay!"
>>> string
"the cow's milk is a-okay!"
>>> string = string.replace(' ','-')
>>> for char in string:
...     if char in "?.!:;/'":
...             string = string.replace(char,'')
...
>>> string
'the-cows-milk-is-a-okay'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple generator expression could be used to accomplish this:

```
>>> s = "the cow's milk is a-okay!"
>>> ''.join(('-' if el == " " else el if el not in "?.!:;/'" else "" for el in s))
'the-cows-milk-is-a-okay'
>>>
```