# How to convert any string into a valid custom pattern using Python?

Tags: python, string

I want my string to only have alphanumeric characters, -, and underscores. Thats it. I am trying to write a method that takes in a user input string and converts it so that it follows the guideline.

My regex is obviously `a-zA-Z0-9_-`. What I want to do is replace all the spaces with the -, and just remove all the other characters that don't fall under my regex.

So, the string `'Hello, world!'` would get converted into `'Hello-world'`. The special characters get removed, and the space is replaced with a -.

What would be the most efficient way to do this using python? Do I have to iterate over the entire string character by character, or is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Does your output include digits?  They are alphanumeric, but fail your regex

Comment: Is the Uppercase to lowercase intentional?

Comment: Could it be, that you need this for forming a url of a title?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh No digits, just A to Z (in both upper and lowercase, dash(-) and underscore(_) allowed. I made a mistake before. Its fixed now.

Comment: @ppasler Yeah, this is for a URL.

Comment: Then have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574042/string-slugification-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with two `sub`s: 1) replace spaces with `-`; 2) remove other unwanted characters:

```
s = 'Hello, world!'

import re
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z_-]", "", re.sub("\s+", "-", s))
# 'Hello-world'
```

If you want to keep digits in your string:

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "", re.sub("\s+", "-", s))
# 'Hello-world'
```

Here `[^a-zA-Z_-]` matches a single character that is not a letter(upper and lower case), underscore and dash, the dash needs to be placed at the end of the character class `[]` so that it won't be treated as range but literal.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is also often used when generating URL names for content. It is implemented in [django.utils.text.slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/utils/text/#slugify). The slugify function converts to lowercase though.
Here is a simplified version of Djangos slugify function that preserves case:

```
import re
def slugify(value):
    value = re.sub('[^A-Za-z_\s-]', '', value, flags=re.U).strip()
    return re.sub('[-\s]+', '-', value, flags=re.U)
print(slugify("Hello World!"))
# Hello-World
```