# What is the use of slug in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

What is slug and why it is used. I'm confused with it. Can anyone help me on it. Thanx

```
 <p><a t-attf-href="/academy/{{ slug(teacher) }}">
     <t t-esc="teacher.name"/></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform a string to a slug that can be used in a url path.

***Example:***(takem from the [website tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/howtos/website.html#id19)).

```
<a t-attf-href="/academy/{{ slug(teacher) }}">
    <t t-esc="teacher.name"/>
</a>
```

You can find more details in [slug](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/website/models/website.py#L87) function documentation.

> Transform a string to a slug that can be used in a url path.
> This method will first try to do the job with python-slugify if present.
> Otherwise it will process string by stripping leading and ending spaces,
>
> converting unicode chars to ascii, lowering all chars and replacing spaces
>
>     and underscore with hyphen "-".

Answer (score 3):

I think it works for removing special characters from a string.

In addons>web>static>lib>underscore.string.js

```js
slugify: function(str) {
      if (str == null) return '';

      var from  = "ąàáäâãåæăćęèéëêìíïîłńòóöôõøśșțùúüûñçżź",
          to    = "aaaaaaaaaceeeeeiiiilnoooooosstuuuunczz",
          regex = new RegExp(defaultToWhiteSpace(from), 'g');

      str = String(str).toLowerCase().replace(regex, function(c){
        var index = from.indexOf(c);
        return to.charAt(index) || '-';
      });

      return _s.dasherize(str.replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, ''));
    },
```

Comment: You can also see this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574042/string-slugification-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

The slug function transforms the parameter(string) to a slug which can be used in a url path. E.g.:

> consider
> `teacher = teacher(1)`

> then
> `<a t-attf-href="/academy/{{ slug(teacher) }}">`

> gives
> `<a href="/academy/teacher-1">`