# Same function acting differently same type of data

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I've probably spent too long on this already but I'm finding it hard to understand why I'm getting a FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: when the only difference I can see is the link.
Using Beautiful Soup

**Objective:**
Download an image and place in a different folder which works fine except on some .jpg files.
I've tried different types of paths and striping the file names but its the same problem.

**Test images:**

http://img2.rtve.es/v/5437650?w=1600&preview=1573157283042.jpg # Not Working

http://img2.rtve.es/v/5437764?w=1600&preview=1573172584190.jpg #Works perfect

Here is the function:

```
def get_thumbnail():
'''
Download image and place in the images folder
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Get thumbnail  image
for  preview in soup.findAll(itemprop="image"): 
  preview_thumb = preview['src'].split('//')[1]    

# Download image 
url = 'http://' + str(preview_thumb).strip()
path_root = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1] 
img_dir = str(path_root) + '\\static\\images\\'


urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, img_dir + show_id() + '_' + get_title().strip()+ '.jpg')
```

Other functions used:

```
def show_id():
  for  image_id in soup.findAll(itemprop="image"): 
    preview_id = image_id['src'].split('/v/')[1]
    preview_id = preview_id.split('?')[0]
  return preview_id

def get_title():
  title = soup.find('title').get_text()
  return title
```

All I can work out is the problem must be finding the images folder for the first image but the second works perfect.

This is the error I keep getting and it seems to be breaking at request.py
[image]

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely the "special characters" in the image filename are throwing `urlretrieve()` (and `open()` used inside it) off:

```
>>> from urllib import urlretrieve  # Python 3: from urllib.request import urlretrieve
>>> url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RUYX.png"

>>> urlretrieve(url, "test.png")  # works
('test.png', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x10b284a28>)

>>> urlretrieve(url, "/tmp/test 07/11/2019.png") # does not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 249, in retrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/test 07/11/2019.png'
```

In other words, the image titles you use as filenames must be properly pre-formatted before using as filenames for saving. I'd just **"slugify" them** to avoid having problems with it at all. One way to do it would be to simply use [`slugify` module](https://pypi.org/project/python-slugify):

```
import os
from slugify import slugify

image_filename = slugify(show_id() + '_' + get_title().strip()) + '.jpg'
image_path = os.path.join(img_dir, image_filename)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, image_path)
```

For instance, that is what would slugify do to `test 07/11/2019` image name:

```
>>> slugify("test 07/11/2019")
'test-07-11-2019'
```

See also:

- [String slugification in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574042/string-slugification-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, yes I think that's a strong possibility, there is spaces in the titles but I thought by stripping them it might work I'll give slugify a study. Cheers

Comment: I've used the slugify and it appears to have removed the error. Thanks, everything is getting slugifyied now!