# Python readlines() and append data to each line output to one line

Tags: python, csv, readlines

I have a csv file with say 3 rows like this:

```
Dallas
Houston
Ft. Worth
```

What I want to do is be able to read those in and make links out of them but have all the lines output on one line. Example output would need to be like this:

```
<a href="/dallas/">Dallas</a> <a href="/houston/">Houston</a> <a href="/ft-worth/">Ft. Worth</a>
```

Here is the code I have thus far and it reads the csv file and outputs but it creates different rows, and I only want one row plus I need to append the html code for hyper links in.

```
f_in = open("data_files/states/major_cities.csv",'r')
for line in f_in.readlines():
    f_out.write(line.split(",")[0]+"")
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Comment: [Note that it’s already possible to iterate on file objects using `for line in file: ...` without calling `file.readlines()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because each `line` in `f_in.readlines()` comes with a newline tacked on to the end. (Try adding a `print(repr(line))` in that loop). What you need to do is remove that newline before `write` ing to `f_out`:

```
for line in f_in.readlines():      
    actual_line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

Your entire code would look like this:

```
import re 

with open('data_files/states/major_cities.csv') as f_in:
    with open('output_file.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            city = line.rstrip('\n')
            f_out.write('<a href="/{}/">{}</a>'.format(
                re.sub(r'\W+', '-', city.lower()), 
                city
            ))
```

The `with` statements take care of `close`ing files, so you don't need those last two lines.

**UPDATE**

As J.F. Sebastian pointed out, it's also necessary to [slugify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django) the city name to achieve the output you want.

Comment: to slugify city name: `re.sub(r"\W+", "-", city.lower())`. Also `cgi.escape(s, quote=True)` might help to avoid broken html.

Comment: Perfect guys, thank you. This has worked just fine for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try the python [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for handling CSV files

```
import csv
file_out = open('file.txt','w')
with open('example.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        col=row[0]
        str="<a href=/" + col.strip().lower()
        str+= "/>" + col + "</a> "
        file_out.write(str)
```

Comment: You're right, but if you're going to suggest a completely different method, you should put some more effort into answering the specific problem the OP has. In this case, reading the CSV wasn't the issue. It was manipulating it afterwards.