# Mapping views.py in Django (Python)

Tags: python, django

I need some help mapping views in Django.  My app is pretty simple -- it's just a status page listing all of our environments and their corresponding apps. So far I have all the env's listed like so:

```
ENV_1
ENV_2
ENV_3
```

But what I want is: (where [app*] would be from app_list in my Environment class -- see below)

```
ENV_1  [app1] [app2] [app3] ...
ENV_2  [app1] [app2] [app3] ...
ENV_3  [app1] [app2] [app3] ...
```

Here's my models.py (app_list = app1, app2, etc.)

**- - UPDATE - -**

```
from django.db import models

class Environment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    app_list = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def format(self):
        app_list = self.app_list or ""
        return (" ".join(["[%s] " % a for a in app_list.split(',')]))
```

And my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from dashboard.models import Environment, Page

def index(request):
    environment_list = Environment.objects.order_by('name')
    context_dict = {'environments': environment_list}

    for environment in environment_list:
        environment.url = environment.name.replace(' ', '_')

    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context_dict)

def environment(request, environment_name_url):
    environment_name = environment_name_url.replace('_', ' ')
    context_dict = {'environment_name': environment_name}

    try:
        environment = Environment.objects.get(name=environment_name)
        context_dict['environment'] = environment
    except Environment.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request, 'dashboard/environment.html', context_dict)
```

And my index.html

```
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>

  {% if environments %}
    td>
        {% for environment in environments %}
            <li><a href="/dashboard/environment/{{ environment.url }}">{{ environment.name }}</a>{{environment.format_apps_list}}</li>
    </td>
  {% else %}
    <strong>There are no environments present.</strong>
  {% endif %}

</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I want to loop through app_list and display them next to each env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your specific issue, you can do something like this:

```
class Environment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    app_list = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def format_apps_list(self):
        app_list = self.app_list or "" #if app_list is blank
        return (" ".join(["[%s] " % a for a in app_list.split(',')])
```

and you can call the `format` helper method in the template - feel free to modify it to your usecase.

```
{% for environment in environments %}
    <li><a href="/dashboard/environment/{{ environment.url }}">{{ environment.name }}</a> {{environment.format_apps_list}}</li>
```

---

I see a few things that could be changed in this app. 
I would also recommend using [`slugs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django) - example this app is great ([django-autoslug-field](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug-field/0.2.3)). One approach for this would be:

```
from django.db import models


class Environment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class App(models.Model):
    environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = AutoSlugField()
```

This would give you the flexibility to analyze which apps are in an environment, and at the same time, what environments does an app belong to.

Your template would be

```
{% for environment in environments %}
    {% for app in environment.app_set.all %}
        {{app.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, now you can process the url by slug, instead of the name - which would eliminate all the `.replace(..)` hacks

Comment: Does `AutoSlugField()` generate slug for each field? I normally use `models.SlugField()`.

Comment: That should be sufficient, but AutoSlugField does a little more - you can set it up for updating the slug when name changes, etc..

Comment: Thanks karthikr! Please forgive me for prying, but how could I implement the first part? Maybe add this to my views? `application_list = format(app_list)` and update: `context_dict = {'environments': environment_list, 'applications': application_list}`

Comment: Check the edit. You can do it in the template directly.

Comment: Ugh I can't get `{{environment.format.apps_list}}` to return anything.  I've even tried just returning `self.name` from that def and I still don't get anything. Thanks again... appreciate your patience.

Comment: It is an underscore, not a `.` I had a typo too. check the edit.

Comment: It's still not populating (updated my code above).  Also cleared my cache and restarted and still nothing.  :(

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you so much for you help and patience karthikr!