# When to use slug field and query string

Tags: python, django, django-urls, slug

I am new in web development in django i don't know when to use slug field and when to use query string parameters in the url.Can anyone suggest me practical differences between them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "slug" in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using slugs keep urls simple and clean, thereby easy to remember. Consider the following example:

```
example.com/post/hello-world/
```

v/s

```
example.com/?post=hello-world
```

Obviously, first one is cleaner.

But query string parameters have their uses too. For example, when you search for an object.

```
example.com/search/?q=hello-world
```

or when you need to pass multiple parameters

```
example.com/search/?q=hello+world&lang=en&something=else
```

Answer (score 1):

In slug related django urls you have a url associated to a view. But you cannot pass querystring parameters to your views.

Ex -`example.com/post/hello-world/` does not pass any parameter to your view function.

But if you want to pass additional parameters to your views, ex,

```
example.com/search/?q=hello-world
```

here `q=hello-world` is a query string parameter passed to your views.
And inside your views function you can get these parameters in `request.GET`
So your views function goes something like this

```
def helloworld():
    qParams = request.GET.get('q', '')
     ....
     ....
```

Hope this helps.