# Passing multiple arguments from django template href link to view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to pass some arguments with a link url href in a template to a view.

In my template :

> ```
> <a href="/print-permission-document/ studentname={{studentinfo.0}} studentsurname={{studentinfo.1}} studentclass={{studentinfo.2}} doctype=doctype-studentlatepermission">Print</a>
> ```

So i am trying to pass 4 arguments to my view.

My view is :

```
def print_permission_document(request, studentname, studentsurname, studentclass, doctype):
file_write(studentname.encode('utf-8')+" "+studentsurname.encode('utf-8')+" "+studentclass+" "+doctype)
return response
```

My  urls.py is :

```
url(r'^print-permission-document/.+$', print_permission_document, name='print-permission-document')
```

But i get below error :

Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
print_permission_document() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)

Comment: What about reading the doc first ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Thanks for the information. It was also helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not* how you specify multiple parameters in a URL, typically you write these in the URL, like:

```
url(
    r'^print-permission-document/(?P<studentname>\w+)/(?P<studentsurname>\w+)/(?P<studentclass>\w+)/(?P<doctype>[\w-]+)/$',
    print_permission_document, name='print-permission-document'
)
```

Then you *generate* the corresponding URL with:

```
<a href="{% url 'print-permission-document' studentname=studentinfo.0 studentsurname=studentinfo.1 studentclass=studentinfo.2 doctype='doctype-studentlatepermission' %}">Print</a>
```

This will then generate a URL that looks like:

```
/print-permission-document/somename/someclass/doctype-studentlatepermission
```

Typically a path does *not* contain key-value pairs, and if it does, you will need to "decode" these yourself.

You can also generate a *querystring* (after the question mark), these you can then access in [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET).

Comment: Thanks Williem, now i get below error Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'print-permission-document' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'studentsurname': 'SURMAN', u'studentname': 'Aleksa', u'studentclass': '4N', u'doctype': u'doctype-studentlatepermission'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['print-permission-document/(?P<studentname>\\w+)/(?P<studentsurname>\\w+)/(?P<studentclass>\\w+)/(?P<doctype>\\w+)/$']
Exception Location: /home/minimus/Env/minimus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508

Comment: @ivbtar: I forgot the hyphen in the pattern for the `doctype`, so `[\w-]+` instead of `\w+`.

Comment: Hi Villiem. Problem continues for one scenario. If there is an empty space in studentname it breaks. It works for "Jack" but if he has double name "Jack John" it fails with Reverse for 'print-permission-document' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'studentno': 20170224L, u'studentsurname': 'K\xc3\x87LAN', u'studentname': 'Jack John', u'studentclass': '12Y', u'doctype': u'doctype-studentlatepermission'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['print-permission-document/(?P<studentname>\\w+)/(?P<studentsurname>\\w+)/(?P<studentclass>\\w+)/(?P<studentno>\\w+)/(?P<doctype>[\\w-]+)/$']

Comment: @ivbtar: then you can change the `\w+`s to `[\w ]+`s, etc. but spaces in URLs are typically *not* a good idea in general. Usually [slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django) are used.

Comment: Thanks you so much Villiem. It worked again. Let me also check slugs.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your URL wrongly. and URL in template is also declared wrongly.

Try this

```
<a href="{% url 'print-permission-document' studentinfo1, studentinfo2, ... %}">Print</a>

url(
    r'^print-permission-document/(?P<studentname>\w+)/(?P<studentsurname>\w+)/(?P<studentclass>\w+)/(?P<doctype>\w+)/$',
    print_permission_document, name='print-permission-document'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error , i corrected it by :

```
url(r'^auth_app/remove_user/(?P<username2>[-\w]+)/$', views.remove_user, name="remove_user"),
```

Use this pattern for passing string

```
(?P<username2>[-\w]+)
```

This for interger value

```
(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)
```