# Using multiple slugs in urls.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to use two slugs in my urls but I keep getting:

```
Reverse for 'tithe' with arguments '(2018, 'February')' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['tithe/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})-(?P<month>[\\w-])/$']
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from tithe import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name="account_login"), name="index"),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('dashboard', views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^tithe/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[\w-]+)/$', views.TitheView.as_view(), name='tithe'),
]
```

dashboard.html

```
<a href="{% url 'tithe' currentYear realMonth %}" class="waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-format-underlined"></i> <span> Tithe </span> </a>
```

Comment: Where are you using a slug?

Comment: yes, I am using a slug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django

Comment: This doesnt really help. The url was working when I was using just 1 slug but stopped the moment I added a second

Comment: There are no "slugs" here, there are two arguments/parameters. Your regex is wrong: `[\\w-]` is missing `+` in the end (whereas `-` is excessive).

Comment: soory this is what I had... It still gives the name error

Comment: The code does not match the error. The pattern you show in the urls.py would work, but that is not the pattern in the error message. (And as others have said, none of them are slugs.)

Answer (score 0):

you can change urlpatterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name="account_login"), name="index"),
 path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
 path('dashboard', views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
 path('tithe/2018/February/', views.TitheView.as_view()),
 url(r'^tithe/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[\w-]+)/$', views.TitheView.as_view(), name='tithe'),
```