# How to save Foreign Key values in DJANGO REST?

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-serializer, django-2.1

Let's say i have models like follow.

```
class Department(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Student(models.Model):
   department = models.Foreignkey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now i need to set `Department(which is created already)` of the `Student` whenever i create the student `instance`.

which is best practice

```
i)  Sending the department id in URI like `departments/{pk}/students`
ii) sending department id in body parameter
```

Comment: department id in the body and the endpoint should look like `/student/` (not adding department in URL and keeping it simple) with an HTTP `POST`

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to send the sensitive data like ids as Post request instead of passing as URL args. if you really want to pass data in URL then please use  [slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django) instead of ID.

also, you can use [DRF model serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)  to save the data

Answer (score 1):

in this case, It'd be better to send department id in the body and keep the endpoint simple as

```
{base}/api/student/
```

make an HTTP POST to this endpoint

```
{
    "department_id":"",
    .
    .
}
```

by taking a look at this endpoint this clearly shows endpoint for operations involving `student` object, I'd say it's more close to `REST` standards.