# Django: How to handle error message in CreateView for UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a generic class based createview, which generates "UNIQUE constraint failed" error. I am able to handle this and redirect it to the same createview form. However i need to send an error msg to the createview saying 'Name already exists'. How to i achieve this.

model.py

```
    class Release(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

    class Feature(models.Model):
        release = models.ForeignKey(Release, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='features')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('name', 'release')
```

view.py

```
    class FeatureCreate(CreateView):
        model = Feature
        fields = ['name', 'summary']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.release_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    from django.db import IntegrityError
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    try:
        a = super(FeatureCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        if 'UNIQUE constraint failed' in e.args[0]:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('feature-create', args=(form.instance.release_id,)))
    return a
```

url.py:

```
    path('release/<int:pk>/feature/create/', views.FeatureCreate.as_view(), name='feature-create'),
```

feature_form.html:

```
    {% block content %}
       <form action="" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="history.back()">
      </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Any suggestions is welcome. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

try to catch expection of the return function itself.. just before return you can send all to form_invalid function, as soon as you catch exception in the form_valid function, something like this inside def form_invalid():
...

```
try:
    return super(FeatureCreate, self).form_valid(form)
except:
    return super(FeatureCreate, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from .models import Feature, Release
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib import messages
class FeatureCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = modelform_factory(Feature, fields=('name', 'release'))
    template_name = 'handle_images/feature_form.html'
    success_url = '/feature/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # super().post() maybe raise a ValidationError if it is failure to save
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    # the below code is optional. django has responsed another erorr message
        if not self.object:
            messages.info(request, 'UNIQUE constraint failed.')
        return response

class ReleaseCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = modelform_factory(Release, fields=('name',))
    template_name = 'handle_images/feature_form.html'
    success_url = '/release/'
```

and:
 add 'django.contrib.messages' to INSTALLED_APP list in settings.py
 add prefix {% extends 'admin/base.html' %} to template for showing messages.info
[image]

Comment: Can you please help in implementing in my class based view. I am not sure how.

Comment: hope it is helpful for you

Comment: Thank you for investing ur time. But here I am trying to add a new feature without explicitly mentioning the release, coz i am already inside the release-feature page.  So i need to use the release-pk to add a new feature. 

And also for my success_url i need to say in the same feature-createpage(with error show). Hope i am making sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement **form_valid**.

```
class FillTimesheetView(UpdateProcessView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        sheet = form.save(commit=False)
        sheet.requester = self.request.user
        try:
            sheet.save()
        except:
            messages.info(self.request, 'UNIQUE constraint failed.')
            return super(UpdateView, self).form_invalid(form)
        ...

        return super(UpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```