# Django 3.0: Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, slug

**I have model named Book in models.py file.**
**And this model has slug field to display details of books**
**Books are being displayed in home.html template and product.html template is to display details of selected book.**

I really don't know much about slugs, and how they work.

**Models.py:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='books_written')
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='books_published')
    price = models.DecimalField('Price', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    upload_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Uploading DateTime', auto_now_add=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='book_category')
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers', null=True,blank=True)
    copyright_proof = models.ImageField(upload_to=book_copyrights_path, null=True,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bookrepo:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def __str__(self):
        return "Title: {} | Authors: {} | Price: {}".format(
            self.title, self.get_authors(), self.price
        )
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'bookrepo'

urlpatterns = [
    path('product/<slug:slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),     
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('about/',views.about,name='about'),
    path('faq/',views.faq,name='faq'),
    path('login/',views.user_login,name='login'),
    path('shop/',views.shop,name='shop'),
    path('signup/',views.registration,name='signup'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "bookrepo/product.html"
    def main(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # kwargs key should be equal to parameter passed from url
        slug_from_param = self.kwargs.get('slug')

def home(request):
    bookz = Book.objects.order_by('title')
    var = {'books': bookz, 'range': 10}
    return render(request, 'bookrepo/home.html', context=var)
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="row">
    {% load my_filters %}
        {% for b in books|slice:":10" %}
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="{{ b.cover.url }}" alt="book-image">
                    <h6>{{ b.title }}</h6>
                    <h6>{{ b.get_authors }}</h6>
                    <h6><span class="price">{{ b.price }}</span></h6>

                    <a href="{% url 'bookrepo:product' b.slug %}" class="btn btn-sm my-btn detail-btn">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>Book Details
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Honestly speaking, I don't know much about slugs and class-based views. I have used only function-based views. And, by searching internet, I found this "slug" way to get url of detail page.

**In html template, I tried this way to: (got the same results)**

```
<a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-sm my-btn detail-btn">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
<a href="{% url 'product' b.slug %}" class="btn btn-sm my-btn detail-btn">
```

Your urls.py, `<slug>` to `<slug:slug>`:

```
path('product/<slug:slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
```

In your views.py, you could get slug as:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "bookrepo/product.html"
    def main(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # kwargs key should be equal to parameter passed from url
        slug_from_param = self.kwargs.get('slug')

        # Your remaining codes
```

**Slug** is nothing but a url. As, you could not add any strings to url, as there can be spaces, you can use slug.
Have a look at [Refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django?rq=1)

Comment: Tried but same results. I am getting this error: Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$'] , as soon as I run server. So issue may be in views.py or urls.py.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But it isn't working same error. I think it's coming from home view. Kindly check that out please.

Comment: what have you done so far... update your question again... I have editted pretty much in my answer and I think it should work now

Comment: Do i have to change something from your last edit according to my code or should i try as it is ?

Comment: Make edit in your question with the latest thing you are trying, and is not working ... **latest**

Comment: is there None value inside slug?? Can you check the slug from admin page

Comment: did u find the issue?