# Django 3.0: Unable to get value in view of selected option in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am at beginner level in django. And, I am unable to get the value of user selected option in view. I have to apply some logic there.

**views.py**

```
def shop(request):

    if request.GET.get('featured'):
        featured_filter = request.GET.get('featured')
        print(featured_filter) #debugging purpose
    else:
        print("\n\nnone\n\n") #debugging purpose

    bookz = Book.objects.order_by('title')
    var = {'books': bookz, 'range': 10}
    return render(request, 'bookrepo/shop.html', context=var)
```

**shop.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'bookrepo:shop' %}" method="GET">
    <select name="featured" class="custom-select-lg custom-select">
        <option selected><h1>Filter</h1></option>
        <option value="pricelow">Low price</option>
        <option value="pricehigh">High price</option>
        <input type="submit" name="featured" value="Filter" />
    </select>
</form>
```

These option things have nothing to do with models.
So right now, I am getting this when I select low price and press button: (in django console)

```
[10/May/2020 00:18:20] "GET /shop/?featured=pricehigh&featured=Filter HTTP/1.1" 200 47486
[10/May/2020 00:18:20] "GET /static/js/js.dom.changer.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Filter
[10/May/2020 00:18:24] "GET /shop/?featured=pricelow&featured=Filter HTTP/1.1" 200 47486
```

As u can see "Filter" is getting printed. But i want is featured's value like pricelow or pricehigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because your request has *two* values for `featured`: `pricehigh` and `Filter`, indeed:

```
/shop/?featured=pricehigh&featured=Filter
```

the second one is caused by the `submit` button. You can simply remove the `name="…"` attribute from the button:

```
<form action="{% url 'bookrepo:shop' %}" method="GET">
    <select name="featured" class="custom-select-lg custom-select">
        <option selected><h1>Filter</h1></option>
        <option value="pricelow">Low price</option>
        <option value="pricehigh">High price</option>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I got your point to remove name attribute from button. In my case it is name="featured"  not name="hellip;". So did i get your point right?

Comment: @Sayyam: the `hellip` was a misrendered ellipsis :) to refer to the attribute part :)

Comment: Its fine :) Is there a way to get value of selected "option" without submit button ?

Comment: @Sayyam: well you submit the form, and then the view aims to read the data. You can use an AJAX call to submit for example a form without visiting a new page: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: I know i am being sticky. But can you answer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692157/django-3-0-reverse-for-product-with-no-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-trie) too? You seem very pro in django. I don't know a thing about slugs and I really need an answer to my problem. Thanks :)