# How to change url to show description instead of id with django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building my first website. But instead of the page being `products/15` (where 15 is the product id), I want it to show the description of the product. How can I achieve that?

**Here are my models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py:**

```
def product(request, id):
    return render(request, 'product.html', {})
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('products/<id>/', post, name='sub-detail'),
]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Maybe this link. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse

Comment: urls are for passing data to the views not showing data to user so it's better to pass id which you can find product by that not description which can be multiple of it in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *babak gholamirad* saids you should use a key that is **UNIQUE** in the model and the URL, just as `id` is but not `description`.

But, if you want to use and display a more "descriptive" KEY than the `id` in the URL: Django's `slugs` ***are made for that***.

[What is a "slug" in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py:**

```
def product(request, slug):
    product_object = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    ...
    return render(request, 'product.html', {})
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('products/<slug>/', post, name='sub-detail'),
]
```

usage:

```
https://<my-domain>/products/my-wonderfull-descriptive-product-name/
```

Comment: PS Adam, If you have some SEO more specific needs, that are not fulfilled by the Django slug mechanism, it's always possible to implement a slug-like mechanism that better suits your needs.