# How to write URL and VIEWS

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

**Below is my model**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Below is the View:**

```
def moviesView(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    context = {
        "movies": movies
    }
    return render(request, 'movies/movies.html', context=context)

def movieView(request, name):
    print(name)
    movie = Movie.object.get(name=name)
    context = {
        "movie": movie
    }
    return render(request, 'movies/movie.html', context=context)
```

**Below are the URLS:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies', moviesView, name='movies'),
    re_path('movies/(\d+)', movieView, name='movie'),
    path('artists', artistView, name='artists')
]
```

**Below is the template:**

```
<h1>Movies</h1>
    {% for movie in movies %}
        <a href="{% url 'movie' movie.name %}">{{ movie.name }}</a>
        <h3>{{ movie.name }}</h3>
        {% for artist in movie.artists.all %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{ artist.wiki }}">{{ artist.name }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

If I click a movie **avengers**, it should carry to another page with movie details of avengers as mentioned in the model:
I need to frame the url as: http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/avengers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify a parameter. But even if you did, it would not accept it, since `\d+` only accepts a sequence of *digits*, not strings.

You can work with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies/', moviesView, name='movies'),
    path('movies/(?P<name>.*)/', movieView, name='movie'),
    path('artists/', artistView, name='artists')
]
```

but it is likely easier to work with `path` instead:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies/', moviesView, name='movies'),
    re_path('movies/<str:name>/', movieView, name='movie'),
    path('artists/', artistView, name='artists')
]
```

It is also *not* a good idea to work with a name. A lot of characters will be [*percent encoded* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) resulting in *ugly* URLs. Django uses [*slugs*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django) to make visually *pleasant* URLs.