# How to reload configurations in Django (Python)

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django.

I made a URL shorter website like bitly for a test, and when users upload new URL, my program upload data to DB.

The problem is that Django doesn't reload urls.py. So if users upload their URL, data is saved in DB, but urls.py doesn't reload, so 404 shows because urls.py is not reloaded, because there are no data about new URL in urls.py.

I've searched in Google, I almost visited every website searched, but I couldn't find the answer.

How do I reload Django configurations without turning off and on the django server?

```
#root/url/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse #HttpResponse
from . import views
from . import models

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.Index),
    path("urlprocess/", views.Process)
]

for i in models.Urllist.objects.all():
    data = path(i.custom, lambda request: HttpResponse("<script>location.href = '{}'</script>".format(i.url)))
    urlpatterns.append(data)
```

```
#views.py (Uploading Code)
def Process(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        custom = data["custom"]

        urllist = models.Urllist.objects.all()

        for i in urllist:
            if i.custom == custom:
                return HttpResponse("customerror")

        #upload
        new = models.Urllist(url=data["url"], custom=custom)
        new.save()

        #reload(sys.modules[settings.ROOT_URLCONF])

        return HttpResponse(custom)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status="500")
```

Comment: Code snippets will be helpful to answer this question

Comment: add a slug 
ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django

Comment: please add what have you done in your forms/views/urls files

Comment: OK I added code